# ColSpan does not apply to TDs when using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

**Working with React and Bootstrap, I have the following code:**

Person class:

```
if (this.state.edit == true){
    return(
    <tr>
        <td className="col-sm-4"><input type="text" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChangeFirstName} ></input></td>
        <td className="col-sm-4"><input type="text" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChangeLastName} ></input></td>
        <td className="col-sm-4">
          <button className="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onClick={this.handleCancelEdit}></button>  { "      " }
          <button className="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-ok" onClick={this.handleRealEdit}></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    );
} else return (
  <tr>
      <td className="col-sm-4">{this.state.firstName}</td>
      <td className="col-sm-4">{this.state.lastName}</td>
      <td className="col-sm-4">
        <button className="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onClick={this.handleEdit}></button>  { "      " }
        <button className="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onClick={this.handleDelete}></button>
      </td>
  </tr>
);
```

The 'upper level' calls this as the following:

```
this.props.people.forEach(function(person) {
  rows.push(
    <Person person={person} key={person.id} />
  );
});

return (
  <table className="table table-striped text-center">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th className="text-center">First Name</th>
              <th className="text-center">Last Name</th>
              <th className="text-center">Delete</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
  </table>
);
```

For some reason neither *className="col-sm-4"* nor *colSpan="4"* nor *colSpan={4}* works, in both cases if the *state.edit is true*, the first column will be very wide compared to the others.

Comment: Is there a `<table>` tag?

Comment: Yes, there is in an upper Component!

Comment: Do you mind adding that to your code?

Comment: Sure, just added them!